# Hide the "Directory and Bash Directory" from Bash Output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, output

When I run my bash script the beginning output is this:

```
    Ryans-MacBook-Air:~ Ryan-Macintosh$ /Users/Ryan-Macintosh/Desktop/bash.sh ; exit;
```

I want to hide that part from the output when I start my Bash program, is there any way to do this? Here is my full bash program below:

```
    #! /bin/bash 
    export PS1=""
    echo "HUGE BLOCK OF TEXT HERE THAT IS TOO LONG TO PASTE"
    $SHELL
```

So in other words I just want my script to show the big block of text from echo, and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

That does not appear to be the output of your bash script, it's the current state of the screen. You could begin your script with a `clear` (or a `reset`).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
clear # Clear (or reset) the screen
echo "HUGE BLOCK OF TEXT HERE THAT IS TOO LONG TO PASTE"
$SHELL # What is $SHELL?
```

Comment: I am so dumb. Thank you so much. By the way "$Shell" is a command that makes it so when the Bash Script is executed, it doesn't close right away, it stays in the script for me.

Comment: @RyanPark On my system, $SHELL is `/bin/bash` (which means it starts *another* shell).